# Elementor PRO - Wordpress Menu to alter section content (show custom template)

Tags: javascript, html, css, elementor

I have big menu on the right column/section. Upon clicking main link from the menu the content in other section should change (ajax load). Likewise clickign on submenu indicator and then clicking on actual link should alter content in other column. Please see this photo:

[Upon choosing "dokumentatsioon" the content on the right ("Pealkiri" would change to "Dokumentatsioon"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBxu1.png)

My questions are: How can I use Elementor Tabs or Croco Jettabs to achieve this?

OR I should approach this through menu widgets and use custom HTML/CSS on the section I Want to alter?

If anyone could point me in the right direction

Cheers.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.